# fetching data from mysql with jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql

I want to fetch some data from mySQL without refreshing the page using jQuery. Can someone please tell me how I can fetch the data if any record in mysql table is updated. For example, following code fetches a number count from the database, if someone add a number in the database and it is updated, how I can display the new number without page refresh? Thanks.

```
<?
$query  = "SELECT number, name FROM members WHERE id=1";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$number = $row['number'];    ?>
```

Comment: You don't want to do this directly. You want to make an Ajax request using jQuery to a PHP script, which then makes the database request. JQuery Ajax docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been mentioned two times already, but I still want to underline it. You would never want a client to be able to access the database directly. It is a serious security risk.

Now to the solution. First of all you will want to set up a PHP-file that you can request with ajax. Let's call this `check.php` and it will look something like this:

```
<?php
// include necessary files to enable connection to the database
$query  = "SELECT number, name FROM members WHERE id=1";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$number = $row['number'];

// send correct content type header of json
header("Content-Type", "application/json");

// we create an array, and encode it to json
// then echo it out while killing the script
die(json_encode(array('numbers'=>$number)));
```

And now onto the JavaScript. The solution is similar to that of Kyle Humfeld, but will not be using the `setInterval`, because it's a really bad practice. The reason behind this is because `setInterval` will not care about the status of your ajax call, if it has finished or not. So you might end up with stacking requests if there's something wrong with the server, and this is not good.

So to prevent this, we instead use a combination of the `success`-callback of the ajax method ([`.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is essentially a shorthand for [`.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) and `setTimeout` to create something that's called [polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29):

```
$(function(){
    // placeholder for request
    var request = null;

    // request function
    var check = function() {
        request = $.getJSON('check.php', function(data){
            // this will log the numbers variable to the dev console
            console.log(data.numbers);
            // initiate a timeout so the same request is done again in 5 seconds
            setTimeout(check, 5000);
        });
    });

    // initiate the request loop
    check();

    // if you want to cancel the request, just do request.abort();
});
```

Also, there's a more advanced solution using a [comet server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) that will push data from the server to the client, but you should try to get the above to work first before digging into comet. If you want to read up on the subject I suggest that you take a look at [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/).

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. I am just wondering if making requests to database every few seconds will use lots of database resources? for example, if 10000 the data is requested on 10000 users pages every few seconds? Also, if the updates might not be so frequent, my silly question is, is sending request after some specific time only way? There is no way to fetch the data ONLY if some record is updated in database? Thanks again.

Comment: @Lucka, I'm afraid you can't make your client aware of updates made to the database without having some kind of polling going on in the background. I'd advocate for a push solution using a comet server if you tend to have that many users. I use [nginx](http://nginx.org/) with [http push module](http://pushmodule.slact.net/) to do stuff like that, but as usual it all comes down to personal preference. Hope this helps!

Comment: good answer but I'm curious how this gets you around the problem of the self-produced DDoS attack.  If you get 1000 users all doing this at the same time, doesn't this have roughly the same effect as the setInterval?  Won't the poll happen once every 5 seconds from every user?  And if so, how is that substantively different than using setInterval to do the same thing?  I'm not in love with setInterval or anything, I'm just not seeing a huge advantage to this approach over that one.  Please help me to understand.  Thanks! =)

Comment: @Kyle, this method will do a request 5 seconds after the server has responded, and only if it has responded. So it will not be hammering requests in the same way `setInterval` would do. And if the load is too high the server will take longer time to respond, which means those 5 seconds will actually be 5 seconds + the time the server took to respond. Hope this makes things clearer :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Pekka mentions, you'll want to make an AJAX call to a PHP page that does the db call.  However, it looks like your problem is a little more complicated than that, since you want to check periodically and update (part of?) your page when a new record is inserted, right?

If so, you should be able to use [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to do that.  It's a native javascript function, and basically just sets up an interval (in miliseconds) after which to run some code.  The thing that makes `setInterval()` different than `setTimeout()` is that `setInterval()` runs repetitively until you tell it to stop (using `clearInterval()`).

So you can use this to make an AJAX call every 30 seconds (or whatever you prefer) to look for new records and update a results div accordingly.

Comment: Please do not condone the usage of `setInterval()`. It is a very bad practice! I will show a better solution to this.

Comment: setInterval has it's positives and negatives, as do other options such as long polling. I wouldn't dismiss it outright without knowing more about the OPs setup.

Comment: @zaius, it is never good to use `setInterval` when polling, no matter what. I hope I've made my explanation clear enough in my answer, otherwise read this [article by Colin Snover](http://zetafleet.com/blog/why-i-consider-setinterval-harmful)

Comment: Oh, I thought you just advocating against polling. Still, with your solution, it depends which you think is worse - queueing of requests, or the poll breaking on error. That could be fixed with an error handler though.

Comment: @zaius, sorry if my first comment was a bit fuzzy. Well, queuing up requests is not something I'd understand why you'd want to do. Imagine a couple of hundred people doing this and the server would ultimately crash. It's like a self-produced DDoS of sorts. But I totally agree about the error handling. Maybe I shouldn't have left that part out ;)

Comment: @Marcus, sorry, that's the only way I know how to do it.  I'll read your answer, though, and hopefully learn something good!  =)